# Auto generated validators being created for Nullable fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have an MVC 3 application which has to be localizable. For my integer MVC is automatically adding Number Validation however I have marked the field as nullable.

This is in my ViewModel:

```
public int? UserValidity
{
   get { return this.Company.UserValidity; }
   set { this.Company.UserValidity = value; }
}
```

This is in my Model:

```
public Nullable<int> UserValidity { get; set; }
```

I have read that MVC adds this validation only for Non-nullable fields but in my case it is also doing it for nullable field.

What could be the reason for it?

Actually in my application all the validation messages have to be multi-lingual so I have to create my custom validators to get these messages from db. But MVC's auto-generated validator is taking precedence over my validators plus it is only in english.